# Remove Line in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, line, flash-cs4

I'm drawing a line using this code:

```
this.graphics.moveTo(posx, posy);
this.graphics.lineTo(2*posx,2*posy);
```

But now I want to remove it, but I can't clear the whole `this.graphics` object because it contains more information that is useful for me.

How can I remove this line without clearing `this.graphics` object? Is there any method to draw a similar line over it to hide or replace the line?

EDIT:

The purple lines are what I want to hide after I draw them:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try drawing the line on a different surface (another `Sprite` or `MoveClip` on top of the original image) - in this case you can hide/clear the top surface which removes the line without actually changing the underlying image.

You start by setting the top surface to be transparent and then you get the `graphics` object that belongs to it and you draw the line on it.

If you then want to 'finalize' the line, you can just merge the two surfaces. After this, removing the line can be much harder, depending on the surrounding pixels.

Comment: Thanks so much. I created a different `Sprite` object; then added it to my main object and now I can hide it using `visible` property as I wanted before. Works like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the line is going over. If it is a uniform color, just draw a line of the surrounding color on top of it.

Comment: I thought your suggestion, but this line can be over multiple surfaces of different colours because the object can be dragged over multiple surfaces (i.e. white, then drag and now is over blue, drag again and now over yellow, etc).

Comment: but can it be that, at one single moment, it is over different colors?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I attach an image for more info: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg716/scaled.php?server=716&filename=screenhunter01feb281015.jpg&res=medium

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think in xxbbcc idea, but it works. Anyways, I upvote your answer for helping me. Thanks :)